# JavaScript Error in Checkbox Validation

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a webpage for clients to register their companies with our organization, they need to confirm if they are authorized to provide us with such information, so I have two checkboxes for them to tick to confirm, i used custom validation for the checkboxes, when i click the submit button it gives me an error "Javascript runtime error: 'validatecheckboxes_clientvalidate' is undefined

here is my asp.net code

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please click checkbox to confirm" ForeColor="Red"                       
    ClientValidationFunction="validateCheckBoxes_ClientValidate"
    OnServerValidate="validateCheckBoxes_ServerValidate">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

here is my c# code

```
protected void validateCheckBoxes_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    if (CheckBox1.Checked)
        args.IsValid = true;
    else
        args.IsValid = false;
}
```

Please tell me what I am missing

Comment: What you´re missing is not the server side validation method, but the client side javascript code you reference in "ClientValidationFunction="validateCheckBoxes_ClientValidate", or did you just forget to post it?

Answer (score 1):

`validatecheckboxes_clientvalidate` needs to be a client side function written in Javascript not a function in C#

```
<script language="javascript"> 
   function validatecheckboxes_clientvalidate(source, arguments)
   {
        ...
   }
</script>
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction(v=vs.110).aspx